# How to create Alias in many to many relationship with a mapping entity using hibernate criteria

Tags: hibernate, join, many-to-many

I will describe my problem with the specific example: I have two entities with a ManyToMany relationship: Operation and User. Hibernate code-generator-tool created a mapping entity called Operation-User including a complex PK. This seems like the following:

```
Operations{
...
private Set<OperationsUsers> operationsUserses= new HashSet<OperationsUsers>(0);
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "operations", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<OperationsUsers> getOperationsUserses() {
    return this.operationsUserses;
}
...
}


OperationsUsers{
...
private OperationsUsersId id;
...
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name = "codUsuario", column = @Column(name = "COD_USUARIO", nullable = false, length = 20)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "codRol", column = @Column(name = "COD_ROL", nullable = false, length = 4)),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "codRefOperacion", column = @Column(name = "COD_REF_OPERACION", nullable = false, length = 35)) })
...
public OperationsUsersId getId() {
    return this.id;
}
...
}

OperationsUsersId{
...
@Column(name = "COD_USUARIO", nullable = false, length = 20)
public String getCodUsuario() {
    return this.codUsuario;
}
...
}

Users.java{
...
private String codUsuario;
...
}
```

As you can see, Operation entity has a OneToMany relationship with mapping table OperaionsUsers but, on the other hand,  there is no relationship mapped between OptionsUsersId and Users  and codUsuario is the join column for both. So my problem is that I want to build a dynamic join query using Hibernate Criteria and, with this purpose, I need to obtain an alias for each relation side, I mean, I got

```
Session session = (Session) em.getDelegate();
Criteria criteria =session.createCriteria(Operations.class);
criteria.createAlias("operationsUserses", "opUsers");
```

But I am not able or I don't know how to create an alias to collect every Users who are related with a specific Operation and use this alias in other queries to get fields from User entity. 
Maybe the best approachment for the solution would be change the model and mapping a OneToMany relationship between OperationsUsersId ans Users

Thanks a lot for help

UPDATED(2015/08/07) I forgot to add that there is a mapping reference to Operations within OperationsUsers as well, that is:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_REF_OPERACION", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Operations getOperations() {
    return this.operations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I get it! The solution was simpler than I thought at the beginning. Just in the moment I post my question I realized that the solution could be changing the mapping from Users to OperationsUsers to put it in the same way is specified for the relationship between Opertaions and OperationsUsers. In this case, the composite pk (OperationsUsersId) does not have any relevance. My classes are finally like the following:

```
Operations{
...
private Set<OperationsUsers> operationsUserses= new HashSet<OperationsUsers>(0);
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "operations", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<OperationsUsers> getOperationsUserses() {
return this.operationsUserses;
}
...
}

OperationsUsers{
...
private Users users;
private Operations operations; 
...
@EmbeddedId
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name = "codUsuario", column = @Column(name = "COD_USUARIO", nullable = false, length = 20)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "codRol", column = @Column(name = "COD_ROL", nullable = false, length = 4)),
    @AttributeOverride(name = "codRefOperacion", column = @Column(name = "COD_REF_OPERACION", nullable = false, length = 35)) })
...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_REF_OPERACION", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Operations  getOperations () {
    return this.operations ;
}
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "COD_USUARIO", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
public Users getUsers() {
    return this.Users;
}
...
}

Users{
...
private String codUsuario;
private Set<OperationsUsers> operationsUserses = new HashSet<OperationsUsers>(0);
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ealUsusUsuarios", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public Set<OperationsUsers> getOperationsUserses () {
    return operationsUserses ;
}
...
}
```

And now, I am able to create both alias:

```
criteria.createAlias("operationsUserses", "opUsers");
criteria.createAlias("operationsUserses.users", "users");
```

Hopefully, this will be helpful for others